# Build all csproj files, except Test projects

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In DevOps you can create a `dotnet build` task where "Path to project(s)" can be set to `**/*.csproj` to build all the projects.

This works just fine, but it (obviously) also builds my `*.Test.csproj` projects.

I found some posts mentioning exclude patterns, so I tried doing the same as in those posts and tried the following combinations:

```
**/*.csproj;-**/*.Test.csproj
**/*.csproj;!**/*.Test.csproj

**/*.csproj;-:**/*.Test.csproj
**/*.csproj;!:**/*.Test.csproj
```

For all attempts I get the following error in the DevOps log:

> Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

So, how can I create a `dotnet build` task to build all my projects *except* the `*.Test.csproj` projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's what I've been using to run all tests except for some of them:

```
  Test/**/*.csproj
  !**/*.Billing.Test.csproj
  !**/*.Queues.Test.csproj
  !**/*.WidgetDataProvider.Test.csproj
```

so by the same token you need to use:

```
  **/*.csproj
  !**/*.Test.csproj
```

as far as I understand, order matter, so this will not work:

```
  !**/*.Test.csproj
  **/*.csproj
```

Comment: Putting them on multiple lines was the solution. Having them on the same line separated by a semicolon didn't for for `dotnet build`, though it does seem to work for `dotnet pack`. Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know the single line with `;` as a delimiter is old style syntax and is depreciated now

Comment: `dotnet pack` only has one line to input project paths, whereas `dotnet build` has a multiline, so I think we're stuck with `;` there for the present.