# Excluding projects when executing the DotNetCoreCLI@2 task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to exclude projects when executing the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task with `build publish` command. I have some test projects (and others) that I don't want to run publish. I have tried file matching according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/file-matching-patterns?view=azure-devops) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56616286/2226873), but I can't get to work. The documentation of the `projects` property doesn't state exactly how to write exclusions and I have tried the different variants shown below.

Variant 1

```
    projects: '**/*.csproj
!**/*.Test.csproj'
```

Variant 2

```
    projects: '**/*.csproj
               !**/*.Test.csproj'
```

Variant 3

```
    projects: '**/*.csproj !**/*.Test.csproj'
```

But all the three reports `##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.`

If I remove the exclusion everything works as expected, but it builds publish of all projects.

Anyone have an advice on how to write it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The following syntax works for me:

```
projects: |
 **/*.csproj
 !**/*Test.csproj
```

Comment: Thanks! it was the `|` which I can't find any documentation on!

Comment: this is common for all the other yaml tasks in azure devops, like pwsh task, or script task, etc

Comment: I tried a lot but this is the only one that will run.

Comment: Take into account that if the command is `publish`, the `projects` parameter will be ignored unless you specifically set `publishWebProjects: false`